# Getting only rows under a distance from reference

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sequential

I'd like to getting rows around a reference line under a condition.

For example, to this table:

```
t <- data.frame( 
name       = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "x", "f", "g"), 
reference  = c(  0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0 ), 
start      = c(  2,  10,  20,  30,  45,  51,  70,  80 ), 
end        = c(  8,  18,  26,  38,  50,  59,  75, 100 ) )

| name | reference | start | end |  
| :--- | :-------- | :---- | :-- |
| a    |    0      | 2     | 8   |  
| b    |    1      | 10    | 18  |  
| c    |    0      | 20    | 26  |  
| d    |    0      | 30    | 38  |  
| e    |    0      | 45    | 50  |  
| x    |    0      | 51    | 59  |  
| f    |    1      | 70    | 75  |  
| g    |    0      | 80    | 100 |
```

If I I want only entries at 5 or less of distance (above or below). That means, the difference between start column of current row and end column of previous one, or, difference between end column of current row and start column of next one. 
The table should be printed as this:

```
| name | reference | start | end |  
| :--- | :-------- | :---- | :-- |
| a    |    0      | 2     | 8   |  
| b    |    1      | 10    | 18  |  
| c    |    0      | 20    | 26  |  
| d    |    0      | 30    | 38  |  
| f    |    1      | 70    | 75  |  
| g    |    0      | 80    | 100 |
```

In this example, I was capable to get `c` because it is less than 5 of distance from `b`, this allowed `c` retrieve also `d`, because `d` are also less than 5 from `c`. That is because all neighbor rows depends of reference, so the reference `b` and `f` are like anchors to the other rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be something like `out <- t %>% filter(end-start>=5)` using `dplyr`. However, your expected output does not reflect this.

Comment: what do you mean by 5 of distance?are u trying to filter based on multiples of 5 with starting row?

Comment: @ghub24 it means the difference between the end of the previous with start of the current.

Comment: @aichao the end value should be from previous row or the star value from the next row

Comment: end of first row is 8, start of 2nd row is 10, that makes a diff of 2, how did that come in ur desired result if  distance is 5? I dont get it

Comment: @ghub24: I don't either. @Aureliano: in any case, try with `lag(end)` and see if you get what you desire. You might also want to use `abs` around the computation for distance.

Comment: thanks for the lag, maybe it will be useful but didnt solve for all cases. Sorry, is not exactly 5, but equal or less than 5

Comment: `d` is 6 from `c`

Comment: @avid_useR thanks. I fixed it.   
This way works but don't make `t$reference == 1` as anchor.
`t %>% filter(lead(start) - end <= 5 | start - lag(end) <= 5)`

Comment: Are we looking at before and after the `reference`, not just after?

Comment: t %>% filter(abs(start - lag(end)) <=5 | abs(end- lead(start))<= 5) gave me your desired output

Comment: @AndS. This fails if there are rows that are 5 apart but are disjoint from the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using `filter` from `dplyr` and `rleid` from `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)

t %>%
  group_by(ID = cumsum(reference)) %>%
  filter(data.table::rleid(abs(start-lag(end, default = start[1])) <= 5) == 1 & ID != 0) %>%
  bind_rows(t %>%
              arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
              group_by(ID = cumsum(reference)) %>%
              filter(data.table::rleid(abs(end-lag(start, default = end[1])) <= 5) == 1 & ID != 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(start)
```

**Input:**

```
  name reference start end
1    a         0     2   8
2    b         1    10  18
3    c         0    20  26
4    d         0    30  38
5    e         0    45  50
6    f         1    70  75
7    g         0    80 100
8    h         0   110 115
9    i         0   117 120
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  name  reference start   end
  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a             0     2     8
2 b             1    10    18
3 c             0    20    26
4 d             0    30    38
5 f             1    70    75
6 g             0    80   100
```

**Data:**

```
t <- data.frame( name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"),
                 reference = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0), 
                 start = c(2, 10, 20, 30, 45, 70, 80, 110, 117), 
                 end = c(8, 18, 26, 38, 50, 75, 100, 115, 120))
```

Note that although `h` and `i` are within a distance of 5, they were not selected because they didn't connect with the `reference` `f`.

Comment: there is any way to check foward and backward in a condition block. I'm try to evaluate how to reduce complexity, cus this way works fine but checks twice all rows and maybe can lead to double time of execution.